# Objective-C design pattern question about delegate

Tags: iphone, delegates

I have a class which implements many delegate methods. How to group the delegate methods into different classes by the protocol they belongs to and use them in the original class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating many classes, a simpler solution is to divide the class into different categories:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
  ...
}
...
@end


@interface MyViewController (TableStuff) <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
// methods related to table stuff
@end


@interface MyViewController (SearchStuff) <UISearchBarDelegate>
// methods related to table stuff
@end
```

Since categories just add methods to the existing class, you could use the any methods declared in a category in the "original" class.

Comment: Thank you! Is it kinda best practice for this solution? Do I really need to separate them in practice?

Comment: @sza: No. It just makes it easier to organize. You could put all delegate methods into the same class without any categories.